# Decorator can't be called

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator, javascript-decorators, babel-decorator

I've started learning Typescript and now I'm learning about decorators but for some reason it just won't work even with the example code from the official website. I'll share you my code, maybe you can help me out here.

```
function Frozen(constructor: Function) {
    Object.freeze(constructor);
}



@Frozen
class Sample {
    id: number;

    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I do get the following error:

> The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.

7 @Frozen

Comment: TL;DR decorator syntax changed from TS 4.x to 5.x. Set your compiler version to 4.x and your code [works just fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMQE5wF4FMwAoIIDOUqI0cqAXCuNPGAJSIDeAUIh4gPIBGAVlmgA6YKixZs+IiTJQKDANysAvq1YABNJhysIAGwCGhQogDKBgLYAHPVhbtOMACbUwICzyyolDjgTDEpOSouM6u7p6oTGycsYhQABYwhELOiAC8iM5KsarKQA).

Comment: Since you're learning the language now, use the newest release version of the language and avoid the old, experimental decorators which are based on an abandoned JavaScript proposal, unless you are using a framework which requires you to do otherwise.